# Change Browser to use No Proxy Capabilities through Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, robotframework

I want to start my Firefox using no proxy.
Currently It is using the system proxy setting.

```
${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].FirefoxProfile()    sys, selenium.webdriver

Call Method    ${chrome_options}   set_preference    network.proxy.type    0

${options}   Call Method     ${chrome_options}    set_preference {"network.proxy.type", 0}

Open Browser    http://cnn.com    browser ff    desired_capabilities=${options}
```

Could anybody helped me here

Comment: If you use SeleniumLibrary then you can pass proxy settings as desired capabilities. See https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Start Firefox with no proxy
    ${proxy}=    Evaluate   sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].Proxy()        sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${direct}=   Evaluate   sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].common.proxy.ProxyType.DIRECT        sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${proxy.proxyType}=    Set Variable    ${direct}
    ${caps}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX        sys, selenium.webdriver
    Evaluate    $proxy.add_to_capabilities($caps)
    Open Browser    http://google.com    Firefox
```